# How to add new AdfBcFactTypes in oracle rules file

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, oracle-rules

I have a Oracle rules file: `MyDeparmentRules.rules`

I have some `AdfBcFactType` nodes with `property`s:

```
<AdfBcFactType id="J}my.project.depart.model.gri.views.GRDetalesDeclaracionsVVO">
            <Name>my.project.depart.model.gri.views.GRDetalesDeclarationsVVO</Name>
            <Alias>Detales</Alias>
            <Visible>true</Visible>
            <CreationUpdateNumber>2362</CreationUpdateNumber>
            <Property id="J}my.project.depart.model.gri.views.GRDetalesDeclarationsVVO.{ViewRowImpl}">
                <Name>viewRowImpl</Name>
                <Alias>ViewRowImpl</Alias>
                <Visible>true</Visible>
                <CreationUpdateNumber>2362</CreationUpdateNumber>
                <IDofType>J}my.project.depart.model.gri.views.GRDetalesDeclarationsVVORowImpl</IDofType>
                <ListContentID>B}nil</ListContentID>
                <Type>my.project.depart.model.gri.views.GRDetalesDeclarationsVVORowImpl</Type>
                <IDofBucketSet>B}nil</IDofBucketSet>
                <Writable>true</Writable>
                <Readable>true</Readable>
                <Local>true</Local>
                <Expression id="L}8242">
                    <IsConstant>false</IsConstant>
                    <ParameterID>B}nil</ParameterID>
                    <Customizable>false</Customizable>
                </Expression>
                <PrimaryKey>false</PrimaryKey>
            </Property>
            <Property 
            .......................
```

1. How do I add new `AdfBcFactType`-s for new view objects?
2. How do I add new `property`-s for these `AdfBcFactTypes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this in the following way:

I downloaded the following:

1. Oracle SOA Composite Editor
2. Oracle Business Rules Designer

by:
Help -> updates -> Oracle SOA Composite Editor